# Get your phalanges off me

Tags: medical

In a movie I heard a character saying "Get your phalanges off me!" Why not "Get your fingers off me"? Is the speaker trying to sound impressive or well-learned?

Thank you!

Comment: I think, basically, affirmative.

Answer (score 1):

Even though phalanges are defined as being the digital bones (digit meaning finger or toe), the character is probably making a direct comparison between hands, fingers, and phalanges. In the context of *just* the hands, these are called the distal phalanges.

The character is more or less probably trying to sound comedic or intelligent (and possibly a combination of the two).

Comment: Perhaps there is also a political notion involved. The Phalangist Party exists in Lebanon and is a Christian organisation, while the Falangists in Spain used to be dictator Franco's cronies. The party symbol consisted of five arrows bound together in the middle, not unlike Mussolini's fasces.

Comment: Re: "In the context of *just* the hands, these are called the distal phalanges": No, the distal phalanges are the phalanges at the tips of the fingers and toes.

Comment: So maybe he didn't mind being gripped, he just wanted you to stop digging your nails into him? : )